# Is it possible to loop in MySQL for sales data?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am trying to build a useful query for our sales team to see how many sales our business has made in the current month, compared to the same point in the previous months.

So if today is the 14th of September, I want to compare how many sales we'd made between 1st - 14th of August and so on to see if we are up or down.

I have created the query to pull the data, but it's not in any kind of loop. Can anyone suggest a way to do this please? Below shows me the data for July 2015...

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(OrderDate),'-',YEAR(OrderDate)) AS MontyYear,
 COUNT(sw_orders.OrderNumber) OrderCount,
    SUM(Gross) GrossIncome
FROM
    orders
WHERE
orders.MasterOrderNumber = ''

AND Date(OrderDate) >= '2015-07-01'
AND Date(OrderDate) <= Concat('2015-07-', DAY(CURDATE()))

order by orders.ordernumber;
```

It feels like I need a variable that is the month number, so starts at "1" for January - then counts up per loop and use is used in the OrderDate part of the query?

Comment: You don't need a loop.  You just need to add a filter on orderDate only going back a certain amount so you don't query the whole darn database.  Also, if you switch the year and month around in your display field, you can use it in an order by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use string literals in the query, but make use of MySql's `DAY` and `MONTH` function:

```
WHERE orders.MasterOrderNumber = ''
AND DAY(OrderDate) <= DAY(CURDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(OrderDate)
```

Comment: This is perfect, but need YEAR adding to the group by to make it more effective: GROUP BY MONTH(OrderDate), YEAR(OrderDate)

Comment: Certainly, either that or add a `WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = ...` - I should have added that.